# WKWebViewからSafariを起動したい

Tags: swift, ios

現在UIWebviewからWKWebviewへの移行作業を行なっております。
しかし、UIWebviewで動作していた、『PDFをアプリ内ではなく、Safariで確認する』という動作が動かなくなりました。

以下が問題のソースになります。
使用言語はSwiftです。

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView!, createWebViewWithConfiguration configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration!, forNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction!, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures!) -> WKWebView! {

    if navigationAction.navigationType == WKNavigationType.FormSubmitted{
            let pattern = "PDFのURL"
            let flag = Regexp(pattern).isMatch(String(navigationAction.request.URL!))
            print(flag)
            print(navigationAction.request.URL!)
            if flag {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(navigationAction.request.URL!);
            }
        }

        if navigationAction.navigationType == WKNavigationType.LinkActivated{
            let pattern = "PDFのURL"
            let flag = Regexp(pattern).isMatch(String(navigationAction.request.URL!))
            print(flag)
            print(navigationAction.request.URL!)
            if flag {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(navigationAction.request.URL!);
            }
        }

        return nil
    }

import Foundation

class Regexp {
    let internalRegexp: NSRegularExpression
    let pattern: String

    init(_ pattern: String) {
        self.pattern = pattern
        self.internalRegexp = try! NSRegularExpression( pattern: pattern, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive)
    }

    func isMatch(input: String) -> Bool {
        let matches = self.internalRegexp.matchesInString( input, options: [], range:NSMakeRange(0, input.characters.count) )
        return matches.count > 0
    }

    func matches(input: String) -> [String]? {
        if self.isMatch(input) {
            let matches = self.internalRegexp.matchesInString( input, options: [], range:NSMakeRange(0, input.characters.count) )
            var results: [String] = []
            for i in 0 ..< matches.count {
                results.append( (input as NSString).substringWithRange(matches[i].range) )
            }
            return results
        }
        return nil
    }
```

移行前のソースはこちらになります。

```
 func webView(webView: UIWebView!, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest!, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

        if navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.FormSubmitted{
            let pattern = "PDFのURL"
            let flag = Regexp(pattern).isMatch(String(request.URL!))
            print(flag)
            print(request.URL)
            if flag {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(request.URL!);
                return false;
            }
        }

        if navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked{
            let pattern = "PDFのURL"
            let flag = Regexp(pattern).isMatch(String(request.URL!))
            print(flag)
            print(request.URL)
            if flag {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(request.URL!);
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true
    }
```

現在は、PDFがSafariではなく、Sebview内で表示してしまうといった状況です。
どこか記述が誤っている箇所があるのでしょうか？

申し訳ありませんが、ご存知でしたら回答お願い致します。

Comment: コードを選択して、`{}`ボタンを押下することでコードをハイライトできます。Markdownの書式に沿っているのでインデントをハイライトと認識してしまい読みづらくなってしまいますのでご活用ください。

Comment: なるほど、質問初めてなので、分かりませんでした。ありがとうございます！

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/66883

Answer (score 0):

Swiftのバージョンの記載をお願いします（おそらく2系かと思います）

さて回答ですが、uiDelegateの

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView!, createWebViewWithConfiguration configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration!, forNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction!, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures!) -> WKWebView! {

}
```

ではなく、

navigationDelegateの

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

}
```

で処理してみてはいかがでしょうか。

以下、実験したソースです。
条件は異なりますが、PDFファイルだったらsafariで開くようになっています。

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView = WKWebView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view.addSubview(webView)

        if let url = NSURL(string: "https://google.co.jp") {
            webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
        }
    }

    func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

        if let url = navigationAction.request.URL where url.pathExtension?.lowercaseString == "pdf" {
            decisionHandler(.Cancel)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
        } else {
            decisionHandler(.Allow)
        }
    }
}
```

お試しください。